# Windows Explorer to open folder then next folder again (Enter not working)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer

I just realized that this annoying bug bothers me for years.

Example: I hit <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to open the Explorer and want to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>  again to choose the first item `C:`. The problem is that `C:` is not focused automatically. Instead I have to press cursor down, cursor up, and then `C:` gets highlighted and I can finally press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open it. This behaviour is the same with all folders in Windows Explorer.

Could anyone enlighten me with the shortcut to directly open the first folder without any cursor keys?

Comment: What happens if you press (space)?

Comment: @Scott: I love you! Boom, this is the one and only key I was searching for, for years! Best answer ever ... I got regarding windows ;) I cannot believe it, so simple!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not sure what the official Microsoft-sanctioned terminology is, but <kbd>Space</kbd> takes the currently *identified* item and *selects* it (gives it *focus*?), so you can operate on it with other keyboard shortcuts, like <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> opens different previews in different versions.

However, generally it opens the My Computer, with all the drives listed. Drive C: is where the cursor is, but it is not automatically highlighted as you pointed out.

There is no specific shortcut, however if you wish to avoid using the cursor keys, you can type the first letter of the name of Drive C: to toggle the selection.

Example: My hard drives are labelled as Local Disk(C:) Local Disk(D:), so I press <kbd>L</kbd> twice to select Local Disk(C:), then you can press Local Disk(C:) and <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. So using this logic you can avoid the cursor keys.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't believe that there is no direct key that brings me into the first folder immediately... hitting the first letter of the name of the first folder is a workaround, thanks for the tip. But pressing `cursor down`, `cursor up` is still faster for me. I really hope that some microsoft guy passes by and can answer this basic question for usability.